# Microcontroller Atmega2549 - high/low bits - Pullups/Pulldowns

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

the exercise was to make a program that reads the pins 2, 3, 4 and 5 of port A and copies the state of these pins to the output pins 3, 4, 5 and 6 on port B and create a function that prints the number of activated switches on the display of a LCD. I understood almost everything but still got some questions. I am kinda of confused with pullups/pulldowns/high/low etc... It would be nice if you can give me some light here! Thank you in avance.

Datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "lcd.h"
#include <stdio.h>

display myLCD;

count(unsigned char numbers){          //*1
    uint8_t stand=0;
    for (uint8_t i=3;i<=6;i++){
        if(numbers&(1<<i))
            stand+=1;
    }
    return(stand);
}

int main(void){

char text[20];  
unsigned int numb;

lcd_init(&myLCD,&PORTD);

DDRA&=~((1<<PIN2)|(1<<PIN3)|(1<<PIN4)|(1<<PIN5));    //Setting PIN2, PIN3, PIN4 and PIN5 of DDRA as input
DDRB|=(1<<PIN3)|(1<<PIN4)|(1<<PIN5)|(1<<PIN6);       //Setting PIN3, PIN4, PIN5 and PIN6 of DDRB as output

for (;;){

    numb=PINA;                                      //Gets the state of pins 2, 3, 4 and 5 of port A, shifts left, and copy on pins 3, 4, 5 and 6 on port B.                
    PORTB=((numb&((1<<PIN2)|(1<<PIN3)|(1<<PIN4)|(1<<PIN5)))<<1);
    sprintf(text,"Aktive Switches:%i",count(~PORTB));     //*2
    lcd_send_string(&myLCD,text,3,1);                                                                   
}

return(0);

}
```

*1: I understand the function counts from 3 to 6 (the 4 outport pins) and if something happens (what do you think is meant by "numbers"), it counts it, but i dont really get what they mean by counting the number of activated switches.

*2: I also dont understand why i have to negate (~) the port b on count(~portb).

There is another program in which i have a similar problem. Here i just have to set the Timer1 to work in CTC mode and toggle the state of 3 leds with an interrupt. But i also cant understand why i have to negate the ports when i want to turn a LED on! Cant it be something with pullups/pulldowns?

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){

time++;

if(time<10){
PORTC=~(1<<PIN0);                             //Red turned on
}

if(time==10){
PORTC=~((1<<PIN1)|(1<<PIN0));                 //Red and yellow turned on
}

if(time==12){   
PORTC=(1<<PIN0);                              //Red turned off
PORTC=(1<<PIN1);                              //Yellow turned off
PORTC=~(1<<PIN2);                             //Green turned on
}

if(time==22){           
PORTC=(1<<PIN0);                              //Red turned off
PORTC=~(1<<PIN1);                             //Yellow turned on
PORTC=(1<<PIN2);                              //Red turned off 
}

if(time==25){
PORTC=~(1<<PIN0);                             //Red turned on
time=0;
}
}
```

Thank you again!

Comment: "why i have to negate the ports when i want to turn a LED on." That's just how the LED is wired. It is very common to use negative logic for I/O. Nothing to do with pullup/down resistors. In the case of an LED, they would provide the default state of the LED before you write a value and configure the port as output - to prevent the "undriven" line from floating in an indeterminate state.

Comment: For the case of an input such as a key closure, the pullup/down is to provide a bias so that the input value does not float when no key is closed. Closing the key then overrides that bias. And again, it is quite common for a key closure to ground the input, ie negative logic, while the resistor provides a pull-up.

Comment: Note that `2549` is not a MCU name. Its a internal Atmel's datashet reference number.